# How to store random value into list? c++

Tags: c++, list, random

I want to store static number of value into my list container in c++. After I run my code, this one crash without any error. Maybe you see what is wrong?
I am trying objectively create list of 100 values and then add random value to a list and later to print it out in cmd.

Thanks in advance.

```
    #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class LIST
{
private:
    int   *r;
    int    n;
public:  
    LIST();         // 1 konstr
    void input();
    void show();  
};
// ====================================
LIST::LIST() // 1 konstr
{
    n = 100;
list<int> r(n);
}
// ====================================
void LIST::input()
{
    r[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    r[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
  }
}
// ====================================
void LIST::show()
{
    cout << "1D input\n";
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cout << i <<  " "; cout << r[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "**********************************************\n";
} 
// ====================================
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LIST wow;
            wow.input();
            wow.show();


    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Time to (learn how to) use a debugger

Comment: What's that `r[n];` supposed to do?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @lecaruyer `LIST wow;` creates an instance (which means the constructor is called)

Comment: @lecaruyer The constructor is called right at `LIST wow;`, think twice.

Comment: `list<int> r(n);` creates a local variable unrelated to the member variable `r`, which stays an uninizialized pointer. That's the problem.

Comment: Basic rule for you: You use pointers/arrays exactly when you really have to. In cases like this, you go with std::vector, std::array or std::list. Also, give your members real names, not "n" and "r". It's quite unusual to name a class all upper case. "input" is a strange name for what it does. Why not go with initialize? Or, since what this does is fundamental for creating an object that does something, simply put it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First, as sayed in comment by πάντα ῥεῖ, list r(n); creates a local variable unrelated to the member variable r, which stays an uninizialized pointer. [Using an uninitialized local variable is an undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Second, In the function LIST::input, you index r from 0 to n-1.
In the function LIST::show, you try to access r from 1 to n. Accessing an out of bounds index is also undefined behavior.

Comment: The `input` function itself already invokes *undefined behavior* because `r` is never initialized